# How to increase a speed of receive data from serial port?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

Weight Scale Machine(FC-5000i model)  was connected with VB application via Serial Port (COM1) and BAUDRATE=9600.

Weight Scale Machine will send a set of data.
Each set includes there commands :

1. UW,+0.000000  g
2. QT,+00000000 PC
3. ST,+000.1064 kg

But I need to display only Weight value
In VB , I use `SerialPort.DataReceived` Event for handling data from serial port.
Each round use  0.5 second for receive one command.

1. Received first command - **Not show anything**
2. Received Second command **-Not Show anything**
3. Received Third command **- Show weight in Kg .**

So My Vb project will display Weight delay 1 second.

User not permit config Weight Scale Machine.

Comment: You're going to need to show the code where you query the scale and get the result back.  I have programmed against a scale with similar serial port settings and when I query it, I get the result back immediately.  So show your code.

Comment: This problem  is my mistake. Because  the SerialPort.DataReceived Event isn't delay. Delegate can resolved this problem because DataReceived Event used other threads but Screen use main thread.